# Ui-Grid header - Add Icon in last header-column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

What I thought would be rather simple, turned out to be not.. Or atleast, I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do:

If I have my grid, as is, I would like a 'plus/add' icon in the top right corner of the grid. So I thought, I edit the `headerTemplate`, that is the point where I get stuck. This is how I have my headerTemplate now:

```
<div role="rowgroup" class="ui-grid-header"> <!-- theader -->
<div class="ui-grid-top-panel">
    <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">
        <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">
            <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper" ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()">
                <div role="row" class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-header-cell col="col" render-index="$index">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix">Icon</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This "adds" the div, but it doesn't fit it in the grid, it places it just outside.. How can I add a column, that is recognised as column, with just the icon in it.

I know I can do this with the gridOptions, and just adding another field without data, but I want this application wide, so I would really like this as a template. And honestly ui-grids way of templating confuses me.. Any help would be really appreciated!

If I am unclear, please let me know and I will try to clarify.

Comment: why not use a header cell template?

Comment: Because I dislike setting that template in all my controllers on the last column, I use the same grid on multiple locations in my application. Correct me if I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around:

```
<div role="rowgroup" class="ui-grid-header"> <!-- theader -->
    <div class="ui-grid-top-panel">
        <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">
            <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">
                <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper" ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()">
                    <div role="row" class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix"
                             ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-header-cell
                             col="col" render-index="$index">
                        </div>

                        <div role="button"
                             class="ui-grid-column-menu-button"
                             ng-click="addRecord()"
                             ng-class="{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}"
                             ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label="i18n.headerCell.aria.columnMenuButtonLabel"
                             aria-haspopup="true">
                            <span class="material-icons" style="padding: 5px; cursor:pointer;">add</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the `ui-grid-column-menu-button` class to show my own icon. This works like a charm, unfortunately you use functionality of the grid menu. I have my menu somewhere else, so this works out for me.

This is the final result:

[image]